# Existing spring project to maven project

Tags: spring, maven, ejb, cxf

Earlier at the time of development my project have not consider the requirement of Maven. Since now project size is quite large and having a lot of dependencies so we have to change our existing spring project to maven project .

can any body suggest me the steps by step implementation of converting spring project to maven project. I'm using Spring, JPA, EJB, Apache CXF.

Comment: How do you build your project now? BTW, Spring and Maven work well together.

Comment: Currently my project is Dynamic web project in eclipse.

Comment: and your background research on Maven tells you what? and what you've tried?

Answer (score 2):

1. Change the project directory structure to adapt maven standard directory structure
2. Change the classpath provider (if you are using) to maven
3. Change project configuration in eclipse to get it detected as maven project
4. configure maven plugins for your build requirement

Comment: Jigar : I'm very new in Maven , Can u please describe these steps in eclipse .